# Autosys Job depends regular expression

Tags: unix, autosys

I am using the Jobdepends command to get a list of jobs stating with tax_check_d_%
I need files like tax_check_d_job
but it returns 
tax_check_djob
tax_check_d_job
tax_check_djob_job

how can i select only tax_check_d_job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When used in a job filter, the `_` (underscore) character is a wildcard that matches exactly one character. This explains why you are seeing the unwanted results coming back -`tax_check_d_job_%` is essentially the same as `tax_check_d_job%`.

Unfortunately I don't think there's a way around this - according to the Autosys 4.0 reference guide, the SQL ESCAPE option is not supported for wildcards.

I would suggest adding one more character onto your search criteria to filter out the unwanted results, running the command multiple times if necessary. E.g. run it with `tax_check_d_job_a%`, `tax_check_d_job_b%`, ... as necessary.

You could also use some custom code to strip out the results you don't want to see. Depending on your needs, this could be a simple as

```
job_depends -d -J tax_check_d_job_% | grep "tax_check_d_job_.*"
```